# How to determine which TLS/SSL protocol was negotiated when using sslvSSLv23?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am using TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL to open a TLS/SSL connection. I currently want to support tls 1.0 to 1.2.

I initialize the IOHandler like this.

```
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(FSocket.IOHandler).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2,sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1];
```

After the connection is made, how can I get which protocol was negotiated for the connection? (Both for ensuring the configuration of both the client and test server is correct, and eventually for statistics purpose).

I checked `SSLContext.Method` after the connection, but it still shows `sslvSSLv23` after the connection. `SSLContext.SSLVersions` shows `[sslvTLSv1_2,sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1]`.

So how do I get that information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specific negotiated protocol is in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLSocket.Cipher.Version` property after the SSL/TLS session is established.  OpenSSL also has a `SSL_get_version()` function (which Indy does not use, but you can call directly).

Comment: `Cipher.Version` doesn't seem to contain the current protocol in use (Or I'm seriously missing something). If, for example, I force using only TLS1.1 on the client, `Cipher.Version` returns 'TLSv1/SSLv3'. I'm going to look into SSL_get_version.

Comment: SSL_get_version did give me the information I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @KenBourassa hmm, `SSL_CIPHER_get_version()` didn't used to be that way, but it looks like the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CIPHER_get_version.html) has changed since I last saw it, so the behavior has apparently changed over time. In that case, stick with `SSL_get_version()`. I might integrate a new property for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLSocket.Cipher.Description